# laço de repetição - while

Tags: javascript, loop, while

Olá, galera! todos bem?
Não estou conseguindo desenvolver um algoritmo em Javascript que **"Peça ao usuário para digitar um número n e some todos os números de 1 a n" usando somente while**. Alguém daria uma help? tks

```
const input = require('readline-sync');

let n = Number(input.question('Informe um numero: '));

let cont = 0;

while (cont <= n) {
  let soma = 1 + cont;

  console.log(soma);

  cont++;
};
```

Comment: Em qual parte está com dúvida? Já conseguiu solicitar o valor de n ao usuário?

Comment: const input = require('readline-sync');

let n = Number(input.question('Informe um numero: '));

let cont = 0;

while (cont <= n) {
  let soma = 1 + cont;

  console.log(soma);

  cont++;
};

Comment: não consigo somar do 1 até o enéssimo número digita pelo usuário e imprimir essa soma. por exemplo: se o usuário digitar 5, o código deveria exibir 15, pois 1 +2 +3 +4 +5 = 15.

Comment: Por favor, [edit] a pergunta e colocar todo esse código nela.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Uma maneira simples de resolver este problema é utilizando o laço de repetição while. Deve-se ler o valor n. Este valor sendo um inteiro válido, devemos somar consecutivamente valores de 1 até o valor n.

### Uma abordagem imperativa

```
const n = parseInt(prompt('Digite um número'))
let inicio = 1
let soma = 0

while (inicio <= n) {
    soma += inicio
    inicio += 1
}
```

### Uma abordagem recursiva

```
somarNumeros = (n) => {
    if (n <= 1){
        return 1
    } else {
        return n + somarNumeros(n-1)
    }
}

const n = parseInt(prompt('Digite um número'))

const soma = somarNumeros(n)
console.log(soma)
```

Nesta abordagem recursiva estamos utilizando uma condição de parada no caso de n seja menor ou igual a 1, desta forma caso o usuário digite um valor negativo prevenimos um loop infinito na execução da recursividade.
Para um valor de entrada por exemplo -5 o valor calculado da função será sempre igual a 1.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda!